# Determining the optimal rearrangement of columns in one matrix to give it the best correlation with another matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am using a probabilistic algorithm that results in a matrix e.g. 8 columns 500 rows. Each time the algorithm is run you get somewhat different values in the matrix (same dimensions) and the columns are scrambled. What I would like to know is, in R, the best way to reorder the columns of the second result so there is the greatest similarity between the matrix from run 1 and the matrix from run 2.

Or maybe I should rephrase this more simply: What is a good way to find the rearrangement of columns in a matrix to maximize the rv coefficient

Comment: Can you tell us what is the rv coefficient?